# C# DateTime.ParseExact with CultureInvariant fails on different environments

Tags: c#

I have a list of dates in string format to convert to `DateTime`. My dates have the following format :

> "Nov 13 2016"

I use `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

I tought that specifying `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` would prevent me getting errors related to specific machine culture, which is not the case. The code works on my development machine, but fails on production server with the following error :

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I logged the following code sample : `DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` on production server and it returns

> "Nov 24 2016"

This is the exact same format I'm trying to parse as a `DateTime`, so I'm really confused about this one....

Comment: Yes, that really *should* be okay on all platforms. Are you absolutely sure the value is *exactly* "Nov 13 2016" without any unprintable characters? Are you able to reproduce this in all cases, e.g. with a hard-coded string?

Comment: how about try to log DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: Add a try catch block to catch the value that throwed an exception. Or try `date.trim` maybe there is white spaces in the string variable

Comment: Also try `MMM  d yyyy` format if day < 10 it differ from the format u are using

Comment: @JonSkeet Parsing hard-coded value works, so unprintable chararcter theory makes sense, especially since my data came from scrapped html data. I'm wondering how this can work locally but I should be ok to go on knowing this. thanks !

Comment: @H.Fadlallah really good point here I'll have to take this in consideration !